# Two promise results called by two different objects are both assigned to one of the objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most probably I made some obvious context or scope mistake, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is a small example to illustrate the issue I am having.

When having the following main.js javascript:

```
$(function() {

    /**
     * Returns a promise that resolvses the provided parameter `something`
     * after 4 seconds.
     */
    function async(something) {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        setTimeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve(something);
        }, 4000);

        return deferred;
    }

    /**
     * Some object with a name and response property.
     */
    var SomeObj = function(name) {

        this.name = name;
        this.response = null;

        this.init();
    }

    SomeObj.prototype.init = function() {

        self = this;

        async(this.name).then(function(response) {

            self.setResponse(response);
        });
    };

    SomeObj.prototype.setResponse = function(response) {

        this.response = response;

        console.log(this);
        console.log(response);
    };

    objA = new SomeObj('a');
    objB = new SomeObj('b');
});
```

That is executed within the empty HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And with jquery installed in the same directory using:

```
bower install jquery
```

A the bottom of the javascript file, two objects are initialized with a `name` property. During initialization, these objects set their `response` property to the same value, that is returned as promise by the `async` function. This function simply resolves the input parameter after four seconds.

With this script I would have expected that (after waiting four seconds) the `response` property of `ObjA` is set to `a` and the `response` property of `objB` is set to `b`. However, the console shows me the following result:

```
> SomeObj {name: "b", response: "a"}
> a
> SomeObj {name: "b", response: "b"}
> b
```

Apparently the `setResponse` function of `objB` is called in both cases. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> ```
> SomeObj.prototype.init = function() {
>     self = this;
> ```

`self` is a [global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), overwritten by the second instance, and referred to by both callbacks. Make it

```
    var self = this;
```

and you code will work. (That said, it's not the best idea to [create a promise in your constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) and asynchronously create that `.response` property)

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for posting this beginners mistake that keeps popping up the javascript-day after a python-night.

Comment: And thanks for the advice. However, in the real case I asynchronously request a 'title' from the server which is upon resolving inserted into the HTML page (it's for a jquery plugin). I do not store the returned value, so I think that is less of an issue.